# ajax success event not working with ios

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax

I have below code (success event) working perfect with Android, Firefox and Chrome but unfortunately not working with ios

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "join.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages, if you add an error callback to the settings is there anything coming back?

Comment: No error message, data inserted successfully for ios and other browsers. But success message not showing for iso only.